# hasClass a removeClass despues addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5

Estoy intentando crear una función la cual busque si existe una clase en un body el cual contiene la id="skin" de manera que cuando se quiera cambiar el theme de toda la pagina, esta función haga todo el trabajo sin necesidad de cambiar cada clase de todos los body, a continuación les muestro:

```js
console.log($('#skin').is('.skin-black, .skin-black-light, .skin-blue, .skin-blue-light, .skin-green, .skin-green-light, .skin-purple, .skin-purple-light, .skin-red, .skin-red-light, .skin-yellow, .skin-yellow-light,'));
```

```html
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" id="skin">
```

aldanux, muy agradecido por la ayuda, pero mira seré mas especifico, creo que el problema es mio al no saber explicar.busco que esta función haga esto, el .is para ubicar en el id:cuerpo si existe alguna de las clases que son skin-algo,  para que luego se remueva y quede algo como esto  y cuando ya este así agregar una clase para que quede de esta manera:  eso intento hacer. lo que busco es cambiar el estilo de todas las vistas de una pagina y no quiero hacer el tedioso trabajo de cambiar body por body, me comprendes?

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar a que te refieres con todos los bodys? ¿No tienes un sólo body con la id skin?

Comment: Nope no se entiende :V

Comment: osea cada vista tiene un body distinto el cual contiene el id=skin, de esa manera cuando quiera cambiar el theme, solo tengo que cambiar el css de skin para que cambien los de todas las vistas.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es esto lo que quieres:

```
if($('#skin')).length == 1){
     $('#skin').addClass('.skin-black, .skin-black-light, .skin-blue, .skin-blue-light, .skin-green, .skin-green-light, .skin-purple, .skin-purple-light, .skin-red, .skin-red-light, .skin-yellow, .skin-yellow-light,');
}
```

Esta función comprueba si existe una clase #skin, en este caso añade las siguientes clases, si lo que quieres es borrar clases utiliza `.removeClass()`.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta, suerte.